# How do I construct a USING statement given the following code?

Tags: c#, using

This works but I wanted to use the "using" keyword.

```
Stream st = null;

st = request.GetRequestStream();
st.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         
st.Close();
```

How would I go about using the keyword "using" here?

using (Stream st = ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using (Stream st = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    st.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         
}
```

Comment: that's all i needed. for some reason I was running into errors. then i realized it was just an extra parenthesis (my code has more parentheses by the sample code above) so i guess i just didn't see it. thx anyway!